# Comparing two growth functions

Tags: asymptotics

Is $$n\ll\omega(n)\ll n^{1+\epsilon}$$ true at every $\epsilon>0$ where $\omega$ is from Landau notation?

Comment: What makes you think $\omega(n)\ll n^{1+\epsilon}$?

Comment: I dont know I am asking... when I wrote on the board to a prof $n^{1+\epsilon}$ he asked me to write $\omega(n)$ (this is with regard to superlinear functions)

Comment: $\exp(n) = \omega(n)$ ...

Comment: @user251257 how about $n^2$ or $2^{2^n}$. Is $n^2=\omega(n)$ or  $2^{2^n}=\omega(n)$?

Comment: @Turbo both. You know, $\omega(n)$ is not a function but a symbol for any function growing asymptotically 'faster' than $n$

Comment: @user251257 What does it mean when my prof said superlinear and I wrote $n^{1+\epsilon}$ and he corrected me and said $\omega(n)$?

Comment: @Turbo no idea. Sorry.